# sed bracket expression and capture group

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have the following set of strings which need to processed through sed :

```
start-pattern
[SYSTEM] capture ............................... FAIL [  2.825 s]
[SYSTEM] capture ............................... FAIL [  2.825 s]
[DEBUG] capture :: capture :: capture .......... FAIL [  0.866 s]
[DEBUG] capture :: me :: capture capture capture FAIL [  0.876 s]
[DEBUG] capture-me ............................. FAIL [  0.361 s]
end-pattern
```

I want write a sed expression (if possible preferable using sed) to get all the string between `[DEBUG]` || `[SYSTEM]` and `FAIL [.*]` for each line for the failed test cases, excluding spaces  and period `.` AND between the text {start,end}-pattern.

The output for the above text should be one or more of the following:

```
capture
capture
capture::capture::capture
capture::me::capture capture capture
capture-me
```

Here is what I have tried, but does not work for all the lines:

```
sed -e 's/\[DEBUG\] \(.*\) :: \(.*\) :: \(.*\) \([^.]FAIL \[.*\]) \[.*/\1::\2::\3::\4/' -e 's/\[SYSTEM\] \(.*\) \..*/\1/'
```

Comment: Have made a small modification to the question, I need to process all lines between the start and end patterns

Comment: how those `start-pattern` and `end-pattern` look like? what are their actual values?

Comment: Apologies! Those are the exact keywords not patterns

Comment: are they exactly named as `start-pattern` and `end-pattern`, literally ?

Comment: cannot you accept a **Perl-one-liner**? very short and simple

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. That is not what you are trying to do so this is not a job for sed. Are you asking for a sed solution because this is a homework problem about sed or will a more appropriate awk solution be acceptable?

Comment: Yes awk or anything else would also be ok as well.

Comment: You say you want the output `...excluding spaces...` but then you show output that includes spaces. Either fix the text or fix your expected output to be consistent with each other and both state/show what it is you actually want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do what you're asking for clearly, simply, robustly, efficiently, and portably on any UNIX system:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/start-pattern/ { inBlock=1 }
inBlock {
    if ( sub(/^\[(DEBUG|SYSTEM)\]/,"") && sub(/FAIL.*/,"") ) {
        gsub(/[[:space:].]/,"")
        print
    }
}
/end-pattern/ { inBlock=0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
capture
capture
capture::capture::capture
capture::me::capturecapturecapture
capture-me
```

Note that you said you wanted the output `excluding spaces and period .` so there are no spaces between "capture"s above. If what you really wanted was just to exclude spaces around `::`s and at the start/end of the output lines then that's just a tweak:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/start-pattern/ { inBlock=1 }
inBlock {
    if ( sub(/^\[(DEBUG|SYSTEM)\]/,"") && sub(/FAIL.*/,"") ) {
        gsub(/[[:space:]]*::[[:space:]]*/,"::")
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|[.]/,"")
        print
    }
}
/end-pattern/ { inBlock=0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
capture
capture
capture::capture::capture
capture::me::capture capture capture
capture-me
```

Comment: Line 4 is not a match

Comment: Its a match for what was asked for  which was for the output to exclude spaces. I added a version that produces the posted expected output instead in case that's what was really wanted and not a mistake.

Comment: Thanks I will try it tomorrow .. can you please explain more

Comment: `excluding spaces and period .` I wanted to be excluded are from the not from the required text.

Comment: Could you also take a look at this question, I wish to understand who to do this in awk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434040/awk-searching-between-two-patterns#comment72013966_42434040

Comment: OK I posted an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136661/discussion-between-askb-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
$ gsed -nE 's/\[(DEBUG|SYSTEM)\] (.*) FAIL.*/\2/;{s/[.]//g;s/ :: /::/g;p;}' file                                                                                                                                                            
capture 
capture 
capture::capture::capture 
capture::me::capture capture capture
capture-me
```

---

The `-n` option stops `sed` printing lines automatically and `-E` switches on extended regular expressions *(this option is documented as -r with GNU sed however `-E` works with both GNU and BSD sed)*.

```
s              # Substitution command
/              # Start of match
\[             # Match a literal [
(DEBUG|SYSTEM) # Match DEBUG OR SYSTEM
\]             # Match a literal ] followed by a space
(.*)           # Match everything after and capture it
 FAIL.*        # Match a FAIL and everything after
/              # Stop match and start replacement
\2             # Replace with the second capture group
{              # If substitution matched applied following commands
s/[.]//g;      # Global substitution of literal .
s/ :: /::/g;   # Global substitution of spaces around literal ::
p;             # Print the result
}
```

Comment: @MarkReed not sure when it was introduced but it's been an undocumented supported option for as long as I can remember.

Comment: unfortunately its the same error when I use, -ne or -nE

Comment: @askb can you run it on the example input only and tell me if you get the error? See it working on GNU sed on linux here https://ideone.com/SmQSqo

Comment: @askb does the line start with `[DEBUG]` or is there whitespace before?

Comment: @askb try updated command, it should produce the output you require.

Comment: Have made a small modification to the question, I need to process all lines between the start and end patterns

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on the sample input:

```
sed -nE '/^.*\[(SYSTEM|DEBUG)\] *(.*[^ ]) *FAIL.*$/{;s//\2/;s/[.]//g;p;}'
```

1. `-n` says "Don't print every line"
2. `-E` turns on extended regular expressions (required for alternation with `|`; without it, not available even as `\|`)
3. `/^.*\[(SYSTEM|DEBUG)\] *(.*[^ ]) *FAIL.*$/` matches *all* of each line we're looking for
4. `{` begins a block of semicolon-separated commands to apply to matching lines
5. `s//\2/` says to replace whatever matched the previous regex with just the part that matched between the second set of `(`...`)`
6. `s/[.]//g` deletes all periods.
7. `p` prints out the line
8. `}` terminates the block.

Comment: Rest of the lines work correctly except for `capture::me::capturecapturecapture` should be `capture::me::capture capture capture`

Comment: So you want to keep *internal* spaces. Check edited answer.

Comment: Have made a small modification to the question, I need to process all lines between the start and end patterns

Answer (score 1):

This does the job as well:

```
sed -n -e '/^\[SYSTEM\]/ ba; /^\[DEBUG\]/ ba; b;'
       -e ':a s/^\[.*\]\(.*\)FAIL.*/\1/; s/[ \.]*//g; \
           :c s/\(capture\)\(capture\)/\1 \2/g; tc; p;'
testcases.txt
```

Outputs:

```
capture
capture
capture::capture::capture
capture::me::capture capture capture
capture-me
```

If the line starts with either `[SYSTEM]` or `[DEBUG]`, the branch is taken and the substitution is done and the result is printed out. Otherwise nothing is done.

And because of the requirement (which wasn't mentioned in the problem description, but was implicitly given by the wished output) there is another construct which keeps the blanks between two successive captures.

In more detail:

1.) `-n`: don't print the pattern space if not explicitly forced by a `p` command.

2.) `ba`: jump to label `a`.

3.) `b`: jump to end of script.

4.) `tc`: jump to label `c` if a succesfull substitution has been made (since last line was read in and since last use of `t`, `T`).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `sed` command combination:

```
sed -En 's/^\[(DEBUG|SYSTEM)\] (.+) FAIL.*$/\2/p' testfile | sed -En 's/(\.|\s(::)\s)/\2/gp'
```

The output:

```
capture 
capture 
capture::capture::capture 
capture::me::capture capture capture
capture-me
```

The second command `s/(\.|\s(::)\s)/\2/gp` will remove all dots `.` and replace `' :: '` with its *trimmed* value `::`

---

The shortened version would look like:

```
sed -En 's/^\[(DEBUG|SYSTEM)\] (.+) FAIL.*$/\2/;s/(\.|\s(::)\s)/\2/gp' testfile
```

Comment: Have made a small modification to the question, I need to process all lines between the start and end patterns

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[]F]' '{gsub(/\./,"")gsub(/ /,"")gsub(/ec/,"e c");print $2}' file

capture
capture
capture::capture::capture
capture::me::capture capture capture
capture-me
```

Comment: Thanks I missed that.